# Firestore Stream closed with status UNAVAILABLE

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a warning shown in the console when I turn off the internet connection. I want to know if it's normal or incorrect and how I can avoid this warning!

```
    W/Firestore( 8864): (23.0.1) [WatchStream]: (c9d068c) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=End of stream or IOException, cause=null}.
    V/NativeCrypto( 8864): Write error: ssl=0xb40000726aa4a958: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
    V/NativeCrypto( 8864): SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0xb40000726aa4a958: I/O error during system call, Success
    W/ManagedChannelImpl( 8864): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
    W/Firestore( 8864): (23.0.1) [WatchStream]: (c9d068c) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to firestore.googleapis.com/142.251.37.202 (port 443) from /:: (port 0): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:142)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:555)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
    W/Firestore( 8864): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:94)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:138)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:94)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:156)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:134)
    W/Firestore( 8864):     ... 15 more
    W/Firestore( 8864): }.
```

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing the `FirebaseFirestoreException.Code` [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code#public-static-final-firebasefirestoreexception.code-unavailable) the warning `UNAVAILABLE` refers to:

> The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a back-off.

The issue happened because there was no internet connection. To an online database, the device should be online most of the time. Connections can drop, but the break needs to be temporary; otherwise, your application will terminate.

Comment: Is there option to skip this process or make app work offline  with Firestor temporary

Comment: You can access data offline in Firestore by enabling offline persistence, I would suggest you to check the official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) on how to do it.